# SDK related error when running flutter pug bet

Tags: flutter

the error is this:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.0-301.2.beta.

Because observable ^0.22.1+4 depends on dart_internal >=0.1.1 <0.2.1 which requires SDK version >=2.0.0-dev.12.0 <2.13.0, observable ^0.22.1+4 is forbidden.
So, because arrazo depends on observable ^0.22.2, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in project...
pub get failed (1; So, because arrazo depends on observable ^0.22.2, version solving failed.)
```

I don't know how to solve this error nor its meaning, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following command:

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Comment: please share pubspec.yaml file and output for flutter doctor -v